# Electronic I94 database records the same entry twice

Tags: usa, overstaying

The US Customs and Border Protection [I94 information site](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/) offers the option to view travel history.
When I look up my travel history record, there appear to be two entries (same date, same location) for my most recent entry to the US. There is only one entry for my most recent departure.

Is this likley to cause any automated systems to beleive I have overstayed? Is there any need to inform the relevant authorities about this. Or is it likley just some artifact of how things are logged/displayed on the website.

Comment: It's all mixed up, according to electronic I-94 I'm not even here

Comment: @user14742 perhaps they thought you were CMaster the last time you entered.

Answer (score 3):

The data displayed should be accurate. If you really want to be sure, you can submit a Freedom of Information Act request to obtain a copy of the official information that USCIS has for you by submitting [Form G-639](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/g-639.pdf).

It shouldn't cause any problems for future entries into the US. A CBP agent will always look at your previous entry information, and he'll see that the two entries are at the same place on the same day. The final decision to admit you to the US always rests with the CBP agent, and not some automated system.